# Alternative to if/else on combinational logic in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, polymorphism

I am working on a program that uses a grid system. The system needs a method that works on every element of the grid, based on the value of its neighbours' `elementType`. What I currently use is something along the lines of the follows:

```
enum ElementType{
    A,B
}

if (neighbourUp.elemType == ElementType.A && neighbourDown == ElementType.A){
    method1();
}

if (neighbourLeft == ElementType.A and current == ElementType.B){
    method2();
}
```

and so on. As you can see this is hard to manage when the types increase. Ideally I would like to use polymorphism here but I feel creating a class for each combination is too much work. Also there may be cases where the method for some combinations is the same.

I would like some advice on how to approach this. Also the `ElementType` needs to be expandable to accommodate new types that may get added later.

Comment: Does every element know it's neighbours?

Comment: Yes I have sort of global dictionary with positions and elements types.

Comment: Is this a game of life type thing? https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/

Comment: @CodingKuma not really. The cells can have more types than just alive or dead.

Comment: I didn't mean that part. I mean is there going to be some sort of given starting "board" where all of the cells have a certain type. Then after each turn the type of each cell is based on a function of the previous types of the adjacent cells?

Comment: Yes there is a fixed start state for the grid. No the current cell type doesn’t depend on other cells. I just want some way to resolve that the given cell has a particular combination of neighbouring cells.

Comment: The easy way is to create a base class and then 9 different inherited cell types.  A grid system has 9 different type : 1) Inner Cell 2-5) Four Corner Cells 6) A Top Edge 7) Left Edge 8) Right Edge 9) Bottom Edge.

Comment: @jdweng these only correspond to directions. In the problem I have multiple types that are independent of the direction. As colours let’s the cells can be red, green or blue. I have method1 that needs to run when cells in the up direction and down direction are both red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***Strategy Design Pattern*** which comes under ***Behavioral Patterns***  to avoid execution of code base on conditions
You can use these links to know more about strategy design patterns

1. https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9ejT8FO-7I

Comment: So essentially each method1 and method2 has its own strategy class and you do the if else in a contexts class. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Yes by doing this you can prevent volition of Open Close Principle. this article https://dzone.com/articles/the-openclosed-principle explain more.

Answer (score 0):

store both of values in array with keys and apply for loop on neighbour and then ElementType, then you can compare using key values until the items in array.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a list of rules and then your main code simply loops around all the cells and then invokes the rules that match for a cell. Then you can add or remove rules relatively easily in the future without changing the main loop logic.

So you need a class that represents a rule, each rule indicates the left/right/up/down types that it matches against and then has a method that is called if the match occurs. Make the matching fields nullable so you can indicate if you do not care what the neighbour type is...

```
class Rule
{ 
    public ElementType? Left { get; set; }
    public ElementType? Right { get; set; }
    public ElementType? Top { get; set; }
    public ElementType? Bottom { get; set; }
    public Action Process { get; set; }
}
```

...in practice your 'Process' would need at least one parameter, a reference to the cell that is being processed. So you can change it to be Action or whatever.